# Android set color to a listview item

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a list view in my application which I'm populating from database. The things that I want to do is depending on some calculations to set the single list view item's text color to red for example. Is there any way to do that?

Here is how I'm populating the listview :

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sql);
    if(cursor.getCount()==0){
        Log.i("Cursor Null","CURSOR IS NULL");
        nocards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        nocards.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        for(cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Title"));
                Log.i("Show Title","Show Title : "+text); 
                collId = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CollID")));
                Log.i("CollId","Collection ID : "+collId);  

                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    for(int k=0; k<ObjectID.size(); k++){
                        if (ObjectID.get(k) == collId){
                            cardsCount = OwnedCardsCount.get(k);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                       cardsCount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TotalCards"));
                }

                String sqlite2 = "SELECT media_id FROM collection_media WHERE collection_id="+collId+" AND media_type_id="+fronImage;
                 Cursor bg = dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sqlite2);
                 if (bg.getCount() == 0) {
                     bg.close();
                 } else if (bg.getCount() > 0) {
                     for (bg.move(0); bg.moveToNext(); bg.isAfterLast()) {

                         int mediId = Integer.parseInt(bg.getString(bg.getColumnIndex("media_id")));
                         Log.i("","mediId : " + mediId);
                         //if(storageID==1){
                            path = rpc.getPublicPathsInternal(servername, fronImage, mediId, Recommended.this);
                        /*} else if(storageID==2){
                            path = rpc.getPublicPathsExternal(servername, fronImage, mediId);
                        }*/
                         Log.v("","path: "+path);
                     }
                 }


                array.add(collId);
                hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put(IMAGE, path);
                hm.put(TITLE, text);
                hm.put(CARDS_COUNT, cardsCount +" Stampii");
                items.add(hm);
        }
    }

        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.main_listview,
                new String[]{TITLE, CARDS_COUNT, IMAGE}, new int[]{ R.id.main_name, R.id.main_info, R.id.main_img});
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                Intent previewMessage = new Intent(Recommended.this, MyCollectionId.class);
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                previewMessage.putExtra("collection_id", array.get(position));
                previewMessage.putExtra("opentype", 1);
                parentActivity.startChildActivity("MyCollectionId", previewMessage);
            }
        });
```

and my main_listview.xml's code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView          
            android:id="@+id/main_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_img"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

         <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So I want to set the textColor of main_name to red. Any suggestions?

Comment: use Custom Adapter.. extending Cursor Adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need class like this:

```
public class StillSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

  public StillSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (timeForRed(position)) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_name)).setTextColor(0xffff0000);
    return view;
  }

}
```

Use it instead of SimpleAdapter in your code and implement timeForRed() method somewhere and will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML for a single list item. Then create your own adapter which overrides `getView()` function. In this function inflate the list item layout, populate controls from the data and set your textview color as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom List Adapter

[Custom Android ListAdapter](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx)

OR

[Android Lists: ListActivity and ListView CustomAdapter](http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/)

May this help you...Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class which extends the `BaseAdapter` class.  The `BaseAdapter` class provides you some override method; the `getView()` is one of them — in this method you can customize your views as you want.

Below is the sample project from this; you can get the idea:

https://ujjwal.opendrive.com/files?51477570_t4x6y